# How to make different authentication numbers everyday without editing code?

Tags: android, html, firebase, api, vue.js

I am making a commuting web with ***vuejs*** and ***firebase***.

I want to make this:
***The boss gives the employee a different authentication number every day, and the employee (user) has to enter the authentication number when pressing the go to work button. (to To make sure he's the one boss hired.)***

For this function, I can make this with v-if (v-if code == 123 like this), but the problem is that I cannot edit the code every day. How can I change the authentication number every day without touching the code?

I would also like to create an app that can easily change the authentication number so that the CEO can use it.

Comment: Verify user at backend. Pass user enter code to backend and check is user entered Code is right or not

Comment: Yes. Like if(verify==111) enter()   or if(verify==222)  enter() But the problem is I cant edit code everyday like the example. I want to edit only numbercode(111, 222) I heard that I have to use API to do this functions but I am not sure what to search it

Comment: get verify code like user enter 111 then take 111 and pass it to server backend where backend will verify is 111 valid then it will return you success response else fail

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this,
Whenever the boss sends the authentication number to a particular employee, save that authentication number in firebase under the employee's details as for eg. - "todaysAuthNo: 123456" , when the employee(user) enters the number and press the go to work button then check whether the number entered by the user matches with the number entered by the boss i.e. check whether it matches with "todaysAuthNo: 123456".
Hence, next time when the boss enters a new authentication number it will get replaced with the old number in "todaysAuthNo" and also the user will need to enter the new authentication number entered by the boss to login.